# Accessing object property key on assignment

Tags: typescript

```
class Item {
    prop:Field;

    constructor() {
        this.prop = this.createField("prop", defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to derive the property key on assignment (in the `cerateField` method). I want to omit the `"prop"` parameter (which I need for the database field name).

Comment: This would require something like Python's descriptor protocol, which doesn't exist in JavaScript (which Typescript compiles to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). Unfortunately, decorators can not convert the type of a property, so the alternative is using decorators in combination with a type converting function, which i named `field` with a lowercase "f". The function is essentially just an empty function forcing the type because the decorator is unable to. The decorator `Field` is doing the actual value converting using the function `createField` with setters and getters.

```
function Field(target: any, propKey: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propKey, {
        configurable: true,
        set(value: any) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, propKey, {
                enumerable: true,
                value: createField(propKey, value)
            })
        }
    })
}

function field<T>(defaultValue: T) {
    return defaultValue as unknown as Field<T>
}

class Item {
    @Field
    prop = field(defaultValue)
}

// This could also be shortened to

class Item {
    @F prop = field(...)
}
```